# Laravel Echo not listening channels

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, websocket, laravel-websockets

I use laravel Echo with Vue and Quasar Framework.
On backend: Laravel 9 and Laravel Websockets (php).
Websockets server working, authentication completed, in Chrome "Network" tab i see websocket connection. All messages in "Network" tab recieved, in Laravel Websockets debug page i see
"subscribed 785317453.777403975 Channel: test" (my browser), but this code, not working.

**Websocket boot file:**

```
  import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import { useUserStore } from "stores/user/user-store";

let echo: Echo;

// "async" is optional;
// more info on params: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
export default boot(async () => {
  const { user: currentUser } = useUserStore();

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

  const echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    authEndpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth",
    key: "laravel_key",
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    auth: {
      params: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + currentUser.websocket_token
      }
    }
  });

  echo.channel('test').listen('test', (e: object| string) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log('test');
  });
  echo.private("App.Models.User.1")
    .listen("App\Events\TestEvent", (e: object | string) => console.log(e));
});

export { echo };
```

**TestEvent file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => 'test'];
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('App.Models.User.1');
    }
}
```

[image: messages received from server]
[image: data from websockets debug page]

Why in "listen" methods not receieved message?

Comment: You sould listen on `echo.private('channel_name').listen('event_name/event_classname in your case TestEvent', (e) => {})`. This should work.

Comment: @AbdullahQasemi, updated question, in question accidentally erased 'App\Events\TestEvent'. It`s not working

Comment: Just put TestEvent there, mine works like that.

Comment: @AbdullahQasemi, changed to only 'TestEvent' and it work! Thank you! But why public channel 'test' not working?

Comment: @AbdullahQasemi, maybe you write it as answer, what could I mark as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on

```
echo.private('channel_name')
 .listen('event_classname in your case TestEvent', 
   (e) => {}
 )
```

And for public channels it is the same thing just change the private function to channel and also in the event class change the PrivateChannel to Channel, it should work the same, but without authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I did noticed [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-echo-not-listening-to-events-using-it-with-laravel-homestead-could-it-be-a-compatibility-issue-with-vue-3), that to `listen` to work, (I have no idea why), it's necessary to put a dot (.) before the event name. After doing that, it worked on my tests:

```
echo
  .channel('public.playground.1')
  .listen('.PlaygroundEvent', (message) => {
      console.log('Event Received', message);
  });
```

Here are my event class:

```
class PlaygroundEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('public.playground.1');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'PlaygroundEvent';
    }

    public function broadcastWith() {
        return [
            'message' => 'Broadcasted Event...'
        ];
    }
}
```